# Facebook iOS SDK posting as a Page

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-access-token

In my iOS app, I want to post on a Facebook Page as the Facebook Page.

I retrieve the page access tokens through the 'me/accounts' endpoint through the user. However, I am not sure how to create an FBSession using that page access token in order to create the post request.

The page access token is a string, and I obtained it correctly by asking the user for 'manage_pages' and 'publish_streams' permissions.

Is there an easy way to do this? I have been looking at the fetchFBAccessTokenData but am not sure how I could use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is - and this took me a long time to find - `initWithSession:FBSession.activeSession` should be `initWithSession:nil`, and the access token should be set direction in the `parameters` NSDictionary field as `[parameters setObject:yourAccessToken forKey:@"access_token"]`.  The access token in the FBSession.activeSession overrides the access_token in the parameters (which it shouldn't IMHO), making the post appear as a "fan" post, instead of a post as the page.

```
[d addObject:yourFetchedAccessTokenString forKey:@"access_token"];
FBRequest *request = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:nil
                                              graphPath:graphPath
                                             parameters:d
                                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Of course now there are other issues, such as how long the access token will last, which requires token caching stategies: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/token-caching-ios-sdk/

Found answer here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/pull/483

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ended up just doing a regular HTTP POST request, bypassing the SDK. I will try your answer out soon and will mark as answer if I am successful!

Comment: *sidenote*: the above code is no longer valid for Facebook iOS SDK 3.x

Answer (score 1):

Thousand thanks for James O'Brien's Code. In addition to that,
you may need the below code:

```
FBRequestConnection *con = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];
[con addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"facebook result >> %@", result);
    [self cancelfbshare:nil];

}];
[con start];
```